# Can the seeds of a type A avocado produce type B trees?

Tags: avocado, pollination

According to [the blog for UC Master Gardener Program of Contra Costa County](https://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=29033)

> The avocado exhibits a type of flowering behavior known as
> “synchronous dichogamy.” An individual flower will open for two days
> and the timing of the male and female phases is distinct. There are
> two flowering types, referred to as “A” and “B” flower types. “A”
> varieties open as female on the morning of the first day. The flower
> closes in late morning or early afternoon. The flower will remain
> closed until the afternoon of the second day when it opens as male.
> “B” varieties open as female on the afternoon of the first day, close
> in late afternoon and re-open in the male phase the following morning.

Even though the behavior of the flowers discourages self-pollination, an avocado plant can still pollinate itself.

- Sometimes there is a small window of overlap while the flowers are switching from male to female.
- A gardener can hand pollinate the flowers by storing flowers or pollen.

For many plants, the offspring grown from seeds are not identical to the parent plant.

**In the case where a type A avocado tree self-pollinates, are the offspring grown from its seeds going to be only type A, or can they be type B also?**