# I Have been Growing an Avocado from a Pit. It is 2 yrs old! How and When to Prune, again?

Tags: tree-care

[image]I have been growing an Avocado, from a Pit, for 2 years! I live in Upstate NYS, so it HAS to be INDOORS at least half of the year. It has been healthy, but, I NEED PRUNING instructions!! I have pruned it, previously, twice. PLEASE HELP! ( Especially if you live in a "Winter" State and have been successful!

Comment: Define "successful" in this question? Success is - growing a large plant? Fruit? What?

Comment: Growing a healthy, well shaped, potted avocado, and eventually have it "fruit"!

Comment: In NY State? Good luck. I've seen one that was a professor's extravagant office plant, (in central NY) having earned himself a big, fairly well-lit office and tenure. It was large and healthy. I don't recall it ever being inclined to fruit. I expect (but don't know, so not an answer) you'll need supplemental lighting that will cost a good deal more to run than you'd spend on avocados at the store.

Comment: And I'm vaguely recalling from another question here that you need two or more plants, that have to be of specific sub-groups, for pollination (thus, fruit) to occur. Suffice to say I've seen a lot of avocado plant's grown from pit in "Winter" states, and I've never seen one fruit. I guess it may be possible to only have one if you hand-pollinate https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/63299/6806